# Javascript get value

Tags: javascript, html

I have a foreach loop and I'm writing some `href(s)` with DOM:

```
var href = document.createElement("a"); 
href.setAttribute("href", uid);
```

Basically I have X href and I want a javascript function fired when a user click on a `href`.

I tried to do add a `onclick` event...

```
href.setAttribute("onclick","displayer("+uid+");");
```

The uid variable:

```
var uid = String(Nuid);
```

even if is a string, and I can clearly see that in Firebug is ok (`console.log`)

But when I click on that link Firebug says:

```
wall.php:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: hEIsrMeIN4M5OoLYTlGUQg9paL73 is not defined
```

and it points me to `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` which is not the error.

The Javascript function is nothing special...

```
function displayer(uid){
 window.alert(uid); 
}
```

Comment: `href.setAttribute("onclick","displayer('"+uid+"');");`

Comment: Enclose the value in single quote `href.setAttribute("onclick","displayer('"+uid+"');");`

Comment: @Rayon: You have added the single quote **outside of** double quote.

Comment: you do not use setAttribute to add events. You use addEventlistener...

Comment: @Pugazh – hehe... Updated.. Thanks...

Comment: @epascarello : `setAttribute` should work fine!

Comment: @Pugazh So does opening a window with a hammer.

Comment: @Pugazh – __epascarello__ is suggesting better _approach_...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
"displayer("+uid+");"
```

produces this:

```
displayer(hEIsrMeIN4M5OoLYTlGUQg9paL73);
```

which is invalid syntax, because that string of characters is not an identifier.  Since it's a string, it needs to be enclosed in quotes.  Something like this:

```
"displayer('"+uid+"');"
```

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer use `addEventListenner` and get the `uid` value from the `href` attribute.

```
function displayer(event) {
  var uidElem = event.target.getAttribute('href');
  alert(uidElem);
}
var href = document.createElement("a"); 
href.setAttribute("href", uid);
href.textContent = "Text Content"
href.addEventListener('click', displayer)
```

Comment: Or just `this.getAttribute('href');`

Answer (score 1):

Do this `href.setAttribute("onclick","displayer('"+uid+"');");`

Answer (score 0):

This is because of a type error.

`href.setAttribute("onclick","displayer("+uid+");");`

Will result in an anchor tag like:
`<a href="abc123" onclick="displayer(abc123)">`

The argument you've set to be prepopulated for the displayer function is not a string and at run time we would be looking for an undefined variable.

If we update this line to include the string quotes around your UID all should be well.

`href.setAttribute("onclick","displayer('"+uid+"');");`

This will result in: 
`<a href="abc123" onclick="displayer('abc123')">`

With a string value being passed to your onclick function.

Answer (score 0):

Use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to add events, do not set them as an attribute.

```
href.addEventListener("click", function() { displayer(uid); });
```

The reason why your code did not work is it is adding it as an attribute. When it renders it renders as

```
<a href="xxxxxx" onclick="displayer(hEIsrMeIN4M5OoLYTlGUQg9paL73)">...
```

so when you click on it, it is looking for the variable `hEIsrMeIN4M5OoLYTlGUQg9paL73`, not a string.

So what do you need to do? Wrap it quotes so it is a string.

```
href.setAttribute("onclick","displayer('"+uid+"');");
```

Now why is this solution bad. Well, first the proper way to add events is with addEventListener. Second if the string inside of uid has a `'` or a `"` it will break the event handler. The string may never have those characters in it, but if they do, that is trouble.